# Parsing disparate excel sheets (pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am reading data from a multisheet excel file, where format is either:

[image]

or

[image]

I am interested in doing regression of Price vs. Quantity, separately for each id class A, B, C,... etc.
When dealing with the first type of sheet I simply use

```
df = pd.read_excel('./question.xlsx', sheet_name = j, header = 1)
```

(the identifier is then taken from the name of the sheet).
When I read the sheet of the second type I get something like:

[image]

that I have difficulty dealing with.

My questions are then

- Question 1 is about the second type of the sheets: How can I separate the data for different classes?
- Question 2 is about the mixture of the two types: I need a parsing procedure that works for both, i.e. I need to detect what type of sheet I am dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to use multiindex:

```
df = pd.read_excel('./question.xlsx', sheet_name = 1, header = [0,1])
```

which results in

[image]

where the data are accessible unambiguously via the Multiindex:

[image]

This however created a problem with missing values for column names (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62658750/6151828)).