# Missing values in pandas column multiindex

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index

I am reading with pandas excel sheets like this one:

[image]

using

```
df = pd.read_excel('./question.xlsx', sheet_name = None, header = [0,1])
```

which results in multiindex dataframe with multiindex.

[image]

What poses a problem here is that the empty fields are filled by default with `'Title'`, whereas I would prefer to use a distinct label. I cannot skip the first row since I am dealing with bigger data frames where the first and the second rows contain repeating labels (hence the use of the multiindex).

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to have empty strings instead of repeating the first label, you can read the 2 lines and build the MultiIndex directly:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('./question.xlsx', header = None, nrows=2).fillna('')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df1.values)
```

it gives:

```
MultiIndex([('Title',        '#'),
            (     '',    'Price'),
            (     '', 'Quantity')],
           )
```

By the way, if you wanted a different label for empty fields, you can just use it as the parameter for `fillna`.

Then, you just read the remaining data, and set the index by hand:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('./question.xlsx', header = None, skiprows=2)
df1.columns = index
```

Comment: This seems like the right path... but I am having some trouble with it. I think you don't need `.index` in the first snippet. Also, I am not sure whether `df1.index = index` is correct - we are dealing with column multiindex here.

Comment: Yep, I used `df1.columns = index` in the last line. Thanks.

Comment: @Vadim: You are right, I wrote 2 typos in 4 lines of code :-( Time for me to have a break...